# onbuttonclick display a hidden fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I click on login button, it says that app is stopped working. But It should be changed to fragment register. Can anyone tell what I should change in following java file ? because I am new for Android, Please kindly help.

```
**AdminFragment.java**

   public class AdminFragment extends Fragment implementsView.OnClickListener {

    EditText etUsername,etPassword;
    Button bLogin;
    public View  mRootView;


    public AdminFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin, container, false);
        etUsername=(EditText)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword=(EditText)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        bLogin=(Button)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.bLogin);

        bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);


        return mRootView;

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment fragment=null;
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.bLogin:
                fragment = new RegisterFragment();
                replaceFragment(fragment);
                break;


        }
    }

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment AdminFragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.tab,AdminFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}




enter code here
```

my Admin Xml file

```
 My xml file in admin fragment
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.swach.wecareapp.fragments.AdminFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
    android:text="Username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPassword"
    android:text="Password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bLogin"
    android:text="Login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>



    register xml file
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res      /android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schppemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.swach.wecareapp.fragments.RegisterFragment">
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Hospital_Name"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etHospital"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etCity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Level"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etLevel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Complaint_Address"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Phone"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPhone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Street"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etStreet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bRegister"
            android:text="Register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>

   </LinearLayout>
```

My Register java file

```
 public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment implementsView.OnClickListener {
Button bRegister;
EditText etHospital;
public View mRootView;


public RegisterFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mRootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    bRegister=(Button)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    etHospital=(EditText)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.etHospital);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    return mRootView;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.bRegister:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

```
My register xml file

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schppemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.swach.wecareapp.fragments.RegisterFragment">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Hospital_Name"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etHospital"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etCity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Level"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etLevel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Complaint_Address"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Phone"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPhone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Street"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etStreet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bRegister"
            android:text="Register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you paste the crash log?

Comment: thank you @Farooq Arshed for urge to answer.  There is my log cat           11-11 10:18:28.936      980-980/com.swach.wecareapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child
            at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.addView(HorizontalScrollView.java:209)

Comment: there is an issue in your xml layout. Please post that in the question.

Comment: HI@FarooqArshed i have used tabhost here is the xml layout

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/bLogin"
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
I have used linear layout with username and password field

Comment: can you paste the whole xml by editing your question and no tin the comments. its difficult to get anything out of your above comment.

Comment: @FarooqArshed hi there you go the xml file

Comment: We need the xml file with the ScrollView, since this one has an error.

Comment: @BarbeSwachGambino also can you paste RegisterFragment class.

Comment: @FarooqArshed there it is thank you for desire to help